# PHP Array_intersect enters undefined offset

Tags: php, arrays, database, wordpress, foreach

I got an array working like this:

```
$listaMaterias[x]['id_materia'] = (value with number and letters random)
$listaMaterias[x]['name_materia'] = (string)
$listaEditoriales[x]['id_editorial'] = (value with n. and l. random)
$listaEditoriales[x]['name_editorial'] = (string)
```

A 'materia' is a book's category. I made a foreach where I get all values from an xml right. Many editorials and materias, where some of them comes repeated.

And then, I make a method with an *array_intersect* to make remove repeated values, but I get an error :

```
    $listaEdits_result = array();  // final results
    $listaMats_result = array();

    $listaEds_first_res = $listaEditoriales[0];
    for ($j = 1 ; $j < count($listaEditoriales) ; $j++ ){
        $listaEdits_result = array_intersect($listaEds_first_res, $listaEditoriales[$j]);
        $listaEds_first_res = $listaEdits_result;
    }

    $listaMts_first_res = $listaMaterias[0];
    for ($k = 1 ; $k < count($listaMaterias) ; $k++ ){

             // Line 285, is this one above

        $listaMats_result = array_intersect($listaMts_first_res, $listaMaterias[$j]);
        $listaMts_first_res = $listaMats_result;
    }
```

And finally, I get this error :

> Notice: Undefined offset: 20 in [URL]/menu-librosnormales.php on line 285
>
> Warning: array_intersect(): Argument #2 is not an array in [URL]/menu-librosnormales.php on line 285

Why access offset 20 if before I count this quantity in every array :

**count($listaEditoriales) :** 20

**count($listaMaterias) :** 14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of ***`$listaMaterias[$j]`*** do ***`$listaMaterias[$k]`*** in second loop below line:-

```
$listaMats_result = array_intersect($listaMts_first_res, $listaMaterias[$j]);
```

***Note:-*** If your aim is to remove duplicates from an array then you can use `array_unique()` easily.

Answer (score 0):

In the second loop you use `$listaMaterias[$j]` but the loop is indexed by `$k`, not by `$j`.

The value of `$j` is `count($listaEditoriales)` because this was the last value of `$j` when the first loop ended. Since `$listMaterias` contains only `14` items, trying to access its `21`<sup>st</sup> item triggers the notice you described.

---

If the purpose of each loop is to compute the intersection of the arrays stored in `$listaEditoriales` (and `$listaMaterias`) then you can do with a single call to [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) using [arguments unpacking](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) (the so-called "splat operator"):

```
$listaEds_first_res = array_intersect(...$listaEditoriales);
$listaMts_first_res = array_intersect(...$listaMaterias);
```

The arguments unpacking operator is available since PHP 5.6. If you need to run the code on older PHP versions then you can use [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) instead:

```
$listaEds_first_res = call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $listaEditoriales);
$listaMts_first_res = call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $listaMaterias);
```

The two lines of code above do the same thing as the entire block of code you posted in the question (faster and without errors).